# get product custom attribute values in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show custom attribute values for products selected by users in WooCommerce, and show them in a table. how should I have a loop through all attributes? any help or documents is appreciated.

Comment: FYI, `if ( ! $attrs || empty( $attrs ) ) {` is more simply expressed as `if ( ! $attrs ) {`.

Comment: if I want to eliminate     $show_custom_attributes    from     foreach ( $show_custom_attributes as $attribute )  ,    and have a loop trough all attributes what should I do?

Comment: I do not Wordpress. Loic answers all of the WP questions on SO.  Otherwise, you might like to ask on [wordpress.se].

Comment: @mickmackusa Note that All plugins related questions (so WooCommerce too) are off topic in [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)… StackOverFlow is the right place for WooCommerce related questions (and any Wordpress plugin too).

Comment: @samiar Your code is not testable. Note that *"the question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**"*. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)